# Error_code 4 when using ET Web Collect

Tags: marketing-cloud

I don't have much knowledge about [Web Collect](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/web_collect/), but I have followed the steps mentioned in ExactTarget (ET) documentation for Web Collect. I created a form in my PHP application, gave ET action along with `ListID`. When I try to submit data I get "No data received" with Error Code 4. I even checked that my input field in form has the same name as that of the field in ET list. I don't know what I am missing.

Comment: Please post your code (without the MID).

Comment: @AdamSpriggs
Here is the code
<form action="http://cl.s6.exct.net/subscribe.aspx?lid=16938" name="subscribeForm" method="post"> 
    <div class="form-field">
        <label class="required-marker">City</label>
        <input type="text" name="City"/>
    </div>
    <div>
       <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
     </div>
</form>

Comment: Why no email address input?  You need to double check your profile attributes and make sure you're including all of the required ones in your form.

Comment: I got it working now, my email field on form and on ET list was mismatching, after getting the mapping correctly, I was redirected to appropriate page. Thanks @Adam for pointing out the email field.